# Taking supremum of inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

If I have something like
$$\int_0^T F(t,f) \leq \int_0^T G(t,f)$$
where f is a function, can I take supremums:
$$\sup_{|f| = 1}\int_0^T F(t,f) \leq \sup_{|f| = 1}\int_0^T G(t,f)?$$
The integrands are positive if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is it ok to assume the variable of integration is t. Its obvious I guess

Comment: @GautamShenoy yes it is $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Let $\int_0^T F(t,f)dt = a(f)$ and $\int_0^T G(t,f)dt = b(f)$

Then Note that for $f:|f|=1$
$$a(f) \leq b(f) \leq \sup_{|f|=1}b(f)$$

Now Rhs is a constant. Hence take sup on LHS to get
$$\sup_{|f|=1}a(f) \leq \sup_{|f|=1}b(f)$$

Answer (score 7):

Yes. If you have an inequality such as $f(x) \leq g(x)$, for all $x \in S$, then you have $g(x) \leq \sup_{y \in S} g(y)$ for all $x \in S$. Hence you have $f(x) \leq \sup_{y \in S} g(y)$ for all $x \in S$, hence you have $\sup_{x \in S} f(x) \leq \sup_{y \in S} g(y)$, or to use the same 'dummy' variable, $\sup_{x \in S} f(x) \leq \sup_{x \in S} g(x)$.

Comment: Can we write $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in S$ in the first sentence instead of "with $x \in S$"? Just to avoid confusion with "there exists $x \in S$ such that $f(x) \leq g(x)$".

Comment: @Lime91 Sure :-).